# Half-bridge IR 2184 discrete component

Tags: voltage, transistors, power, current, resistors

I found datasheet for IR2184 HALF-BRIDGE DRIVER IC [here](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IR2184(4)(S)-DataSheet-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355c955e616d4) . I was hoping to find the IC discrete components circuit from which it was built upon using transistors, diodes, resistor only but its not in the datasheet. Does anyone have the discrete circuit for IR2184 IC? Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean the internal circuitry, or the circuitry with IC and the external components? Sorry, I couldn't understand due to my insufficient English knowledge.

Comment: Why do you need the internal circuit?